# Why are both icons playing the same audio?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've got 2 icons and they are both meant to play different pieces of audio. But at the moment they are both playing the same file. Any ideas?

html

```
 <a onClick="togglePlay()">
     <audio id="sAudio" src="Audio/IngridAlcalde_Castellano_VideoExplicativo.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
     <i class="far fa-pause-circle" id="spanish-pause"></i>
     <i class="far fa-play-circle" id="spanish-play"></i></i>
 </a>

 <a onClick="togglePlay()">
     <audio id="eAudio" src="Audio/IngridAlcalde_English_Explainer.mp3" auto"></audio>
     <i class="far fa-pause-circle" id="english-pause"></i>
     <i class="far fa-play-circle" id="english-play"></i></i>
 </a>
```

css

```
#spanish-play {
    font-size: 400%;
    color: #ED6375;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    display: block;
    width: 6%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: pink;
}

#spanish-play:hover {
    color: rgb(236, 130, 139);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(107, 39, 39);


}

#spanish-pause {
    font-size: 400%;
    color: rgb(218, 113, 127);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    transition: 1s;
    display: none;
    background-color: blue;

}

#english-play {
    font-size: 400%;
    color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 30%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    display: block;
    width: 6%;
    text-align: center;
}

#english-play:hover {
    color: rgb(93, 71, 187);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(107, 39, 39);


}

#english-pause {
    font-size: 400%;
    color: rgb(94, 58, 194);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 30%;
    transition: 1s;
    display: none;

}
```

And finally Javascript

```
var sAudio = document.getElementById("sAudio");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    sAudio.pause()
  } else {
    sAudio.play();
  }
};
sAudio.onplaying = function() {
  isPlaying = true;
};
sAudio.onpause = function() {
  isPlaying = false;
};


// toggle play pause button spanish

var playBtn = document.querySelector("#spanish-play");
var pauseBtn = document.querySelector("#spanish-pause")


playBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    playBtn.style.display = "none";
    pauseBtn.style.display = "block";
})

pauseBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    pauseBtn.style.display = "none";
    playBtn.style.display = "block";
})

var audS = document.getElementById("sAudio");
audS.onended = function () {
    pauseBtn.style.display = "none";
    playBtn.style.display = "block";
};

// toggle play buttons english

var eAudio = document.getElementById("eAudio");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
    if (isPlaying) {
        eAudio.pause()
    } else {
        eAudio.play();
    }
};
eAudio.onplaying = function () {
    isPlaying = true;
};
eAudio.onpause = function () {
    isPlaying = false;
};


// toggle play pause button english

var playBtnE = document.querySelector("#english-play");
var pauseBtnE = document.querySelector("#english-pause")


playBtnE.addEventListener("click", function () {
    playBtnE.style.display = "none";
    pauseBtnE.style.display = "block";
})

pauseBtnE.addEventListener("click", function () {
    pauseBtnE.style.display = "none";
    playBtnE.style.display = "block";
})

var audE = document.getElementById("eAudio");
audE.onended = function () {
    pauseBtnE.style.display = "none";
    playBtnE.style.display = "block";
};
```

I know I also have a lot of repeating code in the javascript here. So as a second question how can I refactor this to not repeat as much code.

Pretty new to all of this so appreciate any advice!

Thanks.

Comment: you are using same toggle function `togglePlay` for both english and spanish. Make them separate or use calling object to identify click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try cleaning your html. I think you miss a `preload="` in your second `<audio>` tag. You also closed each `<i>` tag two times.

Also, in your javascript, you have two functions with the same name `function togglePlay()`. Try using different names for each. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user10045300 I edited my answer. I added some comments about your javascript functions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your HTML gets confused.

Have a look at how to proper use [the audio-tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp)

You also have double of `</i>`. Please be strict for HTML.
I have moved the `<i>` out of the anchor. You should assign actions directly to them instead of them all.

Also you use the same function to start the music. Give the functions an index and differ them like that in order to prevent this.

```
<a onClick="togglePlay_Explicativo()">
<audio id="eAudio" autoplay ">
<source src="Audio/IngridAlcalde_Castellano_VideoExplicativo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</a>
<i class="far fa-pause-circle" id="spanish-pause"></i>
<i class="far fa-play-circle" id="spanish-play"></i>

<a onClick="togglePlay_Explainer()">
<audio id="eAudio" autoplay ">
<source src="Audio/IngridAlcalde_English_Explainer.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</a>
<i class="far fa-pause-circle" id="english-pause"></i>
<i class="far fa-play-circle" id="english-play"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean up your HTML part. There are extra close tags.